# Doctrine 2 Mapping One-to-Many / Many-to-One

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm converting my application from doctrine1 to doctrine2.4
i did automate mapping from database and I'm missing some relations:

Table : Products
productid,title ,price

Table : LocationProducts
id , productid , loctionid , qty

so each LocationProducts row have 1 product, each product can be on few locations

on mapping under the locationproducts class i got :

```
 /**
 * @var \Products
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="productid", referencedColumnName="productid")
 * })
 */
private $productid;
```

and under product Model i don't have the relationship , i have tried to add it but its fails : its says productid mapping is already exists

this is my target query :

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('p.productid,lp.qty AS totalqty')
    ->from('Products','p')
    ->innerJoin('p.LocationProducts','lp')
    ->setFirstResult( $offset )
    ->setMaxResults( $limit )
    //getDQL
    ->getQuery();
```

and its returns the error:

```
Class Products has no association named LocationProducts
```

What am i missing ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the mapped by attribute annotation.

```
<?php
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Phonenumber", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
public $phonenumbers;
```

Refer to mappedBy in this link :- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetomany

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: i finally figured it out

/**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LocationProducts", mappedBy="productid")
     *
     */
    protected $LocationProducts;

mappedby mean the field
thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that there is no association, so you need to add it. Currently your relation is unidirectional and you cannot join on `p.LocationProducts` since it does not exist.

Comment: i know that i need to add it, but first its should have created it automatically from the db converting and 2nd when i try to define the relation its says "Property "productid" in "Products" was already declared, but it must be declared only once"

Comment: No, it should not have created it automatically. You need to add the LocationProducts property in the Product class.

Comment: this is what i said i tried to add it but its throws an error
on the annoations driver its just ignore it on the xml driver i tried

<one-to-many target-entity="LocationProducts" mapped-by="LocationProducts" field="productid">
        <cascade></cascade>
        <order-by>
            <order-by-field name="locationid"/>
        </order-by>
    </one-to-many>

and its says Property "productid" in "Products" was already declared,

Comment: If the property is declared twice, you need to remove one instance of it, the error is quite clear. But if you have other issues, you should consider posting other questions. This question is already answered.

Comment: but its the same issue , i can't figure out how to map LocationProducts to Products Entity.

Comment: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional